# How to do Rotation matrix in CGAL

Tags: cgal

CGAL has an `Aff_transformation_3` class that can handle the translation, rotation and scale. It is easy to set up an object for translation, but I am struggling to do it for rotation.

For example, I have a Vector_3 object vector and want to get a matrix for rotation from vector to Z-axis. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

CGAL::Rotation is only for 2D rotation. If you want to perform a rotation in 3D you have to provide the full matrix. 
You can check this out for an example: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Aff__transformation__3.html#aa9c9cce6a5b44397a1af5351cebfaaaa

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I started preparing elements of the matrix, and need the cos(theta), the angle between unit vector z and vector mid. Their type is Vector_3. I tried to calculate it with:  

  Kernel::FT thetaCos = (mid * z) / CGAL::sqrt(mid.squared_length());

but have problem with CGAL::sqrt(). Can you help me?

Comment: If you are using cgal 5.0 or higher, you can use Compute_approximate_angle_3 : https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classKernel_1_1ComputeApproximateAngle__3.html
Else, for the sqrt, I think you want to use CGAL::approximate_sqrt().